# Transparent Background not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm making a small simple game in HTML and Javascript but I've run into an error. The sprite I've made on the "canvas" is not able to reach the canvas borders (the edge of the game world). After looking at it alot, I deduced it wasn't the code but the fact that the background of the image isn't transparent. But this makes no sense because the image file does have a transparent background.

How can I completely get rid of the background? Or is something in the code causing the sprite to have it's own border?

**Image file:**

[image]

**What it looks like when run**

http://prntscr.com/4btb32

**Code:**

```
// JavaScript Document

var canvasWidth = 800;
var canvasHeight = 600;

$('#gameCanvas').attr('width', canvasWidth);
$('#gameCanvas').attr('height', canvasHeight);

var keysDown = {};

$('body').bind('keydown', function(e){
 keysDown[e.which] = true;
});

 $('body').bind('keyup', function(e){
 keysDown[e.which] = false;
});

var canvas = $('#gameCanvas')[0].getContext('2d');
var FPS = 30;
var image = new Image();
image.src = "ship.png";

var playerX = (canvasWidth/2) - (image.width/2);
var playerY = (canvasHeight/2) - (image.height/2);

setInterval(function() {
update();
draw();
}, 1000/FPS);

function update(){
if(keysDown[37]){
    playerX -= 10;
}
if(keysDown[38]){
    playerY -= 10;
}
if(keysDown[39]){
    playerX += 10;
}
if(keysDown[40]){
    playerY += 10;
}

playerX = clamp(playerX, 0, canvasWidth - image.width);
playerY = clamp(playerY, 0, canvasHeight - image.height);

}

function draw() {
canvas.clearRect(0,0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
canvas.strokeRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
canvas.drawImage(image, playerX, playerY);
}

function clamp(x, min, max){
return x < min ? min : (x > max ? max : x);

}
```

Thanks,

Ab

Comment: Well to let the sprite reach the edges of map you could simply crop the extra transparent space from the edges of the sprite. But if you want to do it the right way look into pixel collision detection. even with a transparent background the edges of the image will remain the edges. However with collision detection set up you can check if the actual sprite is contacting the edges/other objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your clamp function is making is so the x and y values are always between 0 and the canvas size minus the image size. This makes it so that your image will never leave the canvas (making the full image always on the canvas), and your image size is actually a bit larger than the ship image. The transparency of the image has nothing to do with the ship leaving the canvas, it has to do with the size. If you want to be able to have the ship leave the canvas, or get right next to the edge then decrease the size of the image to not have a border on it.

Alternatively you could have your clamp function clamp to 0 - image.width and canvasWidth + image.width  (or height). This will allow the ship to fully disappear off the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not the sprite has a transparent background, the height and width of the image are still being used.  you need to create your sprite in a way that the ship fills the entire canvas that you are painting it on.

The image will be as wide and tall as your background... so your ship wont reach the edge because there is still a background on your image that extend beyond your ship.